# Displaying results of a stored procedure via a dataset in an MVC 4 View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have spent a lot of time on this, but i can't seem to get it to work. I have a legacy web forms app that i am rewriting in MVC. It has all bussiness logic coming from stored procs and in the iterest of time, I decided to reuse the BAL(bussiness layer) and DAL. Here is what I have:

Model

```
public class GridDisplay
    {
        public List<string> columnNames { get; set; }
        public List<string> fieldValues { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult PatientInfo()
    {

        var model = new PatientInfoViewmodel();
        ViewBag.countries = model.FillCountryDropDown();
        ViewBag.studies = model.FillStudyDropDown();
        SearchElements SE = new SearchElements { StudyID = "PRMDEMO" }; 
        List<string> fields = new List<string>();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = pibl.PopulateData(SE);
        var display = new List<GridDisplay>();

        display = model.BuildGridData(SE);

        ViewBag.columns = display[0].columnNames.ToList();

        ViewBag.fields = display;
        return View();
    }
```

List of GridDisplays:

```
public List<GridDisplay> BuildGridData(SearchElements SE) //(string country, string studyID, string patientid, string lastname)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();`enter code here`
        ds = pibl.PopulateData(SE);
        GridDisplay display = new GridDisplay();
        List<GridDisplay> displayList = new List<GridDisplay>();
        string strtemp = string.Empty;
        display.columnNames = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            display.columnNames.Add(row["label"].ToString());
        }


        display.fieldValues = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[1].Rows)
        {

        display.fieldValues = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataColumn column in ds.Tables[1].Columns)
            {
                if (column.Caption != "STUDY" & column.Caption != "PATIENT_ID")
                {
                    display.fieldValues.Add(row[column].ToString());
                }
                if (column.Caption == "PATIENT_ID")
                {
                    strtemp = row[column].ToString();
                }
            }
            display.fieldValues.Add(strtemp);
            displayList.Add(new GridDisplay() { columnNames = display.columnNames, fieldValues = display.fieldValues});
        }


        return displayList;
    }
```

The displayList has everything I need and I am able to display the columns, but not the fields. Below is the view portion that pertains to this(one of my versions)

```
   <div id="dvDynamicPatient" style="overflow: auto;">
        <table id="gvDynamicPatient">
            <tr>
                @foreach (var col in @ViewBag.columns)
                {
                    <th id="gridHeader" style="  white-space: nowrap;">

                        @col
                    </th>
                }
            </tr>
            <tr>
                @foreach (var item in @ViewBag.fields.fieldvalues)
                {
                                <td id="gridCell" style="border-style: solid; color: #000000; white-space: nowrap">
                        @item
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div
```

Answer (score 0):

Understanding models is a beautiful thing. I did figure this out. To recap, I have a stored procedure that returns two result sets via a dataset. Dataset.Tables[0] has header strings and Dataset.Tables[1] contains the information to be displayed.My task was to create an MVC 4 application to view this and then some.

Model

```
 public class GridDisplay

    {
        public List<string> columnNames { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> fieldValues { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller

```
     public ActionResult PatientInfo()
        {
            var model = new PatientInfoViewmodel();
            // build dropdown lists
            ViewBag.countries = model.FillCountryDropDown();
            ViewBag.studies = model.FillStudyDropDown();
            SearchElements SE = new SearchElements { StudyID = "PRMDEMO" };

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = pibl.PopulateData(SE);
            var gridDisplay = new GridDisplay(); 

            gridDisplay = model.BuildGridData(SE);
            return View(gridDisplay);
        }
```

View

```
   <div id="dvDynamicPatient" style="overflow: auto;">
        <table id="gvDynamicPatient">
            <tr>
                @foreach (var col in Model.columnNames)
                {
                    <th id="gridHeader" style="white-space: nowrap;">
                        @col
                    </th>
                }
            </tr>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.fieldValues.Count; ++i)
            {
                <tr id="row" style="white-space: nowrap;">
                    @foreach (var item in Model.fieldValues[i])
                    {
                        <td id="col" style="white-space: nowrap;">
                            @item
                        </td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
```